# How many subgroups does $\mathbb{Z}_5$ have

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic

How many subgroups does $\mathbb{Z}_5$ have (addition)?

here is my Cayley table (sorry for the formatting):

$\ \ \ 0\ 1\ 2\ 3\ 4\
\\
0\ 0\ 1\ 2\ 3\ 4
\\
1\ 1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 0
\\
2\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 0\ 1
\\
3\ 3\ 4\ 0\ 1\ 2
\\
4\ 4\ 0\ 1\ 2\ 3
$

So I think that there are 5 subgroups because each row contains all the possible entries. Is this right?

Answer (score 9):

For $p$ prime, $\langle \mathbb Z_p, +\rangle $ has only two subgroups: the trivial group $\{0\}$, and $\mathbb Z_p$ itself.

If $G$ is a group, then you will find that each row and each column contain every group element exactly once. So that feature, when seen in a Cayley table, gives no information as to how many subgroups a group contains.